# How to use javascript libraries in Angular 2 Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a library which has a function structure like this..

```
$.fn.et_menu = function ( options ) {
var settings = $.extend({
type: "default", // can be columns, default, mega, combined
animTime: 250,
openByClick: true,
delayTime: 0
}, options );
```

which should be called like

```
$('.menu.side-menu').et_menu({
type: "default",
delayTime: 0
});
```

Any help.. how to integrate this in Angular..

Ive included the library in my index.html file and 
did

```
declare var et_menu: any;
```

in my component.ts file..

Any help would be rally greatful.

Comment: did you add the javascript file to `src/assets`

Comment: You have included the library on your index.html file... and? What happened? How should runtime know that et_menu is some property of object fn of object $? Have you tried window["$"].fn.et_menu?

Comment: Which version of Angular?

Comment: Its angular 2, Ive made jquery workable, but cannot figure how to call function

$('.menu.side-menu').et_menu({
type: "default",
delayTime: 0
});

Its saying

Property 'et_menu' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

Answer (score 2):

**Step One**

```
npm install jssha --save [using jssha for this demo]
```

It it is your own custom file place it in the scripts array of angular-cli.json skip this step 1

**Step two**

```
Add the jssha scripts file in .angular-cli.json file
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jssha/src/sha.js" ]
```

**Step three** 
    Adding a var in component to be used as a global variable

```
//using external js modules in Angular Component
declare var jsSHA: any; // place this above the component decorator
shaObj:any;
hash:string;
this.shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
this.shaObj.update("This is a Test");
this.hash = this.shaObj.getHash("HEX")
```

Take a look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq). It has a working example and a question for the same with typings and without it.

Comment: thank you but I've looked into it very carefully... thats a bit different i guess..

Comment: What is different please tell may be i can help

Comment: I guesa you need to add two variables one for jquery and other for et then it will work

Comment: $('.menu.side-menu').et_menu({
type: "default",
delayTime: 0
});

Comment: In case of  normal page we do something like..

$('.menu.side-menu').et_menu({
type: "default",
delayTime: 0
});

Comment: declare two vars `declare var et_menu: any;` and `declare var $: any;`

Comment: Yes thanks but once I do that, I get some error in html view like 

$(...).et_menu is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (homenav.component.ts:28)
    at j (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:2:29999)
    at k (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:2:30313)
....... and so on..

Comment: check if u are able to use jquery , this error commes when et is not a function